# Updating the text displayed in a paragraph when the cursor hovers over an image on HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, mouseover, kineticjs

I have a few images on an HTML5 canvas, and I want to call a function that will update the text displayed in an HTML `<p></p>` tag whenever the cursor hovers over one of these images.
The images are being drawn to the canvas using the following function:

```
function drawBox(imageObj, img_x, img_y, img_width, img_height) {
    console.log("function drawBox is drawing the description boxes");
    var canvasImage = new Kinetic.Image({
      image: imageObj,
      width: img_width,
      height: img_height,
      // puts the image in the middle of the canvas
      x: img_x,
      y: img_y
    });

    // add cursor styling

    imagesLayer.add(canvasImage);
}
```

I've tried adding an on `mouseover` function to each of the images by adding some code to call the function I have that updates the contents of the paragraph to this function, so my `drawBox` function now looks like this:

```
function drawBox(imageObj, img_x, img_y, img_width, img_height) {
    console.log("function drawBox is drawing the description boxes");
    var canvasImage = new Kinetic.Image({
      image: imageObj,
      width: img_width,
      height: img_height,
      // puts the image in the middle of the canvas
      x: img_x,
      y: img_y
    });

    // add cursor styling


    canvasImage.on("mouseover", function(){
        //displayAssetDescriptionTip();
        console.log("displayAssetDescriptionTip() is being called on mouseover event");

        });

    imagesLayer.add(canvasImage);
}
```

When I view my page with this function as it is above, and hover the cursor over one of the images that the function has been added to, the log that I've added to my `mouseover` function is being displayed in the console- so I know that the mouseover is working correctly.

However, the problem I'm having is with the function that I want to call from within the `mouseover` event. You'll see above, that I've commented out a call to the function `displayAssetDescriptionTip()` in my `mouseover` event. This is the function that I want to be called in the event of the cursor hovering over these images, however, it seems that it always changes the text in the paragraph to the text belonging to the first description box... i.e. if the cursor hovers over any of the images that I've added the `mouseover` event to, then the text is changed to the text belonging to the first image, rather than the image that the cursor hovered over.

The function is:

```
function displayAssetDescriptionTip(){
    if(canvasImage.id = "assetBox")
        document.getElementById('tipsParagraph').innerHTML = tips[34];
    else if(canvasImage.id = "liabilitiesBox")
        document.getElementById('tipsParagraph').innerHTML = tips[35];
    else if(canvasImage.id = "incomeBox")
        document.getElementById('tipsParagraph').innerHTML = tips[36];
    else if(canvasImage.id = "expenditureBox")
        document.getElementById('tipsParagraph').innerHTML = tips[37];
    else return;

    console.log("displayAssetDescriptionTip being called");
}
```

Anyone have any idea why it always changes the text to the text for the first image, and not to the text corresponding to any of the other images? I've set it to change the text to a different element of an array depending on which image the cursor is hovering over, so it should display a different element from that array for each image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your function displayAssetDescriptionTip you are using the = assignment operator instead of the == comparison operator hence your first if condition is always matched.

The fonction corrected :

```
function displayAssetDescriptionTip(canvasImage){
    if(canvasImage.id == "assetBox")
        document.getElementById('tipsParagraph').innerHTML = tips[34];
    else if(canvasImage.id == "liabilitiesBox")
        document.getElementById('tipsParagraph').innerHTML = tips[35];
    else if(canvasImage.id == "incomeBox")
        document.getElementById('tipsParagraph').innerHTML = tips[36];
    else if(canvasImage.id == "expenditureBox")
        document.getElementById('tipsParagraph').innerHTML = tips[37];
    else return;

    console.log("displayAssetDescriptionTip being called");
}
```

Don't forget to pass canvasImage as argument to your event handler

```
 canvasImage.on("mouseover", function(){
        displayAssetDescriptionTip(canvasImage);
        });
```

Comment: That would make sense- at least in theory... but I've changed each of the `if` statements to `if(canvasImage.id == "assetBox")` etc, and now when viewing the page in the browser, I still get the console log "displayAssetDescriptionTip() is being called on mouseover event" whenever the cursor hovers over one of the images, so the function is clearly being called, but the text in the paragraph is not being updated... any ideas why this is?

Comment: I changed my code in the way you have done in your first suggestion- but I'm now having the problem described above, where the contents of the paragraph isn't being updated at all.

Comment: Hey, I've put `canvasImage` inside the brackets for the call to `displayAssetDescriptionTip(canvasImage);`, but although I still get the message "displayAssetDescriptionTip() is being called on mouseover event" in the console when hovering over one of the images, the text in the paragraph is still not updated...

Comment: try to console.log(canvasImage.id) to see which value it has

Comment: It's saying that the value is undefined... I'm wondering if that's anything to do with the parameter I'm using when calling the function? i.e. when I call it, I'm using the line: `displayAssetDescriptionTip(canvasImage);` but in the definition, I have left the paranthesis empty, i.e. `function displayAssetDescriptionTip(){...` should I use the same parameter in the `()` for the definition as I have in the call to the function?

Comment: I've tried putting the `canvasImage` variable in the parenthesis for the function definition, i.e. `function displayAssetDescriptionTip(canvasImage){... `, but when I hover the cursor over those images, the text still doesn't change, and the console logs that the value of `canvasImage.id` is still undefined... any ideas why this is?